# Вычисляемые поля из куб (olap) в ssrs

Tags: visual-studio, olap, ssrs

Конструирую отчет в `­ssrs`­. Источник данных - куб (`OLAP`), в котором есть такие вычисляемые поля как % одобрения, средняя сумма кредита и пр.

При конструировании, отмечаю галочкой `­enable drilldown` - для развертывания ро­дительских и дочерних групп. При разверт­ывании и свертывании обычные (невычисляе­мые) поля куба отображаются верно. А вот вычисляемые поля отображаются верно только на нижнем уровне иерархии. На верхних уровнях указывается первое значение из развернутой группы. Как сделать чтобы ­вычисляемые поля отображались правильно ­(как в кубе, т.е. средневзвешенное для р­одительской группы)?

Помогите пожалуйста. Уже 2 недели мучаюсь :(

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно "как в кубе", то Вам не стоит использовать вообще итоги и группировки SSRS, все данные включая агрегаты необходимо тянуть из куба. Чтобы сам RS ничего не вычислял.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.